# Print a webpage in PDF format

Tags: powershell

I have a requirements where I need to print a webpage in PDF format.
Created one dashboard and shared it using permalink(a permanent static hyperlink to a particular web page).

I need to print this page in pdf.

Can any body let me know if it possible.(Need to automate this using powershell so that can be downloaded automatically. )

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Hi , linux windows any will do

Comment: Open in browser, hit print, select a pdf printer?

Comment: No I want it be in CLI way... As I need to Automate this.

Comment: if either Linux or Windows is fine then this should be on https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

While it is potentially possible, I do not know of any tools that can do this from the command line. Any tool would have to render/draw the page the same way a web browser would in order to create the PDF file. (Simple HTML is not that hard--until you add in CSS, JavaScript, devices, and so on.) Web pages are also generally dynamic in the layout engine, responding to various events such as resizing, changing elements, reflows, and so on.

There are several ways to do it from a GUI and directly from a full web browser. What you might look in to are tools to automate GUI scripting in order to load a browser from the command line and then send it mouse and keyboard events to "print to pdf", activate a we extension, or take a screenshot, etc. That is likely the best you will find for automating such a ask.